# Virtualize WIndows 7 for Windows Media Center and other Linux containers

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, windows-media-center

Currently, I have Windows 7 as the host OS on an Intel Core i5-6500 with the sole purpose of running Windows Media Center using an HDHomeRun Prime for cable TV and Handbrake converted DVDs.

Long story short, I'm looking to consolidate machines and I want to build an AMD Ryzen 5600G to be my sole home server everything.

The problem is, I don't know if I can run Windows 7 as a guest OS *and* lets me output Windows Media Center over HDMI (with hardware acceleration).  As an aside, I don't subscribe to any DRM channels, so that isn't an issue for me.

Another thing I want to do is leverage the Ryzen for other in-house services, maybe a minecraft server, fast transcoding (via https://github.com/donmelton/other_video_transcoding) and be a JellyFin server so I can get Cable TV and Movies across all of my TVs and devices.

Eventually, when JellyFin gets to a point where I consider it "better" than WMC, I'll finally turn off Windows 7, but until then I need to run both.

There seems to be a few virtualization options (proxmox, esxi, virtualbox) and I'm not familiar with any of them.  I'm only familiar with Docker containers.

The situation I want to understand right now is: is it possible to have a Windows 7 VM with hardware acceleration over HDMI (via the Ryzen) and also has access to a USB port that has the IR Dongle?  In addition, while Windows 7 is running, can I do hardware transcoding in a different container (or host OS native) knowing that I'm using the same GPU as the Windows 7 VM?

Comment: The problem is, I don't know if I can run Windows 7 as a guest OS and lets me output Windows Media Center over HDMI (with hardware acceleration).    .... Probably not with today's VM apps.  Why not use a supported OS as a hardware (not virtual) host for your server?

Comment: @John - WMC was dropped between Windows 8.1 Update 1 and Windows 10 1507

Answer (score 1):

Given that you appear to want to virtualise Windows 7 for the sole purpose of running Windows Media Center, I would propose a slightly different solution.

[This github page](https://github.com/garyan2/wmcsetup/) offers a version of Windows Media Center which has been packaged up into an MSI that installs into any location. This avoids a Windows update deleting the eHome folder and you can do a repair if anything goes wrong.

In addition, all the satellite/transponders in the resource file have been updated, the tuner limit is now 32 for each type and buttons that no longer work (due to MS servers being removed) have been disabled/removed.

I've been running it on Windows 10 and it works well.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I discovered that github page around the time I posted my question and I discovered that WMC on Win 10 doesn't support cable cards, which is what I need for the HDHomeRun Prime.  If you know a way to make the cable cards work with WMC, I would love to hear it.

Comment: @TimReddy Oh that's a shame. Sorry but I don't use cable cards so I cannot be much help. Hopefully someone else will have a better solution.